# Install Microsoft Sql Server on Pop!_OS

Tags: sql-server, linux, repository, apt-get

I am trying to install Microsoft SQL Server on the latest Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (jammy) but receiving following errors:

```
sudo apt-get install mssql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I was also not able to add the repository using the information given at [microsoft sql server link for Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16) :

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
```

Can someone guide me on how to resolve these dependencies and install MS Sql Server on Pop!_OS?

Comment: SQL Server is not supported on 22.04 (yet). Notice the *first line* of the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16#prerequisites-2): *"You **must** have an **Ubuntu 20.04 machine** with at least 2 GB of memory."* (Emphasis mine)

Comment: oh! Any idea by when it may be supported or an alternative method to install it? BTW Pop os is based on Ubuntu and i have 4 gb ram.

Comment: Use a container (there are docker images, however, I run several SQL Server instances in LXC as I'm more familiar with that), use a VM, or downgrade to 20.04 (the latter is likely not a good option).

Comment: I apologize i am not aware of docker images...is there a tutorial to setup docker images for Pop!_OS to get MS Sql Server on it?

Comment: For Docker, they're on the same documentation you linked: [Run & Connect - Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver16)